# Error in creating nested table involving inheritence

Tags: oracle, orm, plsql, user-defined-types

I have a somewhat complex structure as follows :

```
create or replace type user_typ as object(
  user_id number(19,0),
  username nvarchar2(40 char)
);
```

I inherit an applicant_typ from this :

```
create or replace type applicant_typ under user_typ (
  resume_text nclob
);
```

My design involves jobs to which applicants can apply. To this end, I create an application_typ as follows :

```
create or replace TYPE Application_typ AS OBJECT (
  application_id NUMBER,
  candidate applicant_typ,
  time_of_app DATE
);

CREATE TYPE Application_tab IS TABLE OF Application_typ;
```

And now I want to create an object type called Job_typ, and a table containing those objects, wherein there will be a nested table for applications :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Job_typ AS OBJECT (
  job_ID NUMBER,
  company_ID NUMBER,
  description NVARCHAR2(1000),
  name NVARCHAR2(200),
  application Application_tab,
  MAP MEMBER FUNCTION job_no RETURN NUMBER,
  MEMBER PROCEDURE no_of_applicants 
);
```

All of this works fine. The issue is when I try to create a table of type Job_typ :

```
CREATE TABLE Job_tab OF Job_typ 
NESTED TABLE application STORE AS application_nt;
```

This doesn't work, giving the error :

```
SQL Error: ORA-02320: failure in creating storage table for nested table column APPLICATION
ORA-22913: must specify table name for nested table column or attribute
02320. 00000 -  "failure in creating storage table for nested table column %s"
*Cause:    An error occurred while creating the storage table for the
       specified nested table column.
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT : I tried some different things. If I change application_typ as follows :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Application_typ AS OBJECT (
  application_id NUMBER,
  candidate User_Typ, -- NOTE: This attribute is now of type User_typ instead of the inherited type
  time_of_app DATE,
);

 CREATE TYPE Application_tab IS TABLE OF Application_typ;
```

Then everything else works, and I am able to create the Job table. Why do I get the error on using the inherited type?

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following in Oracle 11.2.0.1 and didn't get any error. I made a slight change though:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE user_typ AS OBJECT
(
    user_id NUMBER (19, 0),
    username NVARCHAR2 (40 CHAR)
) NOT FINAL;                            -- << Notice the NOT FINAL keyword

create or replace type applicant_typ under user_typ (
  resume_text nclob
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Application_typ AS OBJECT
(
    application_id NUMBER,
    candidate applicant_typ,
    time_of_app DATE
);

CREATE TYPE Application_tab IS TABLE OF Application_typ;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Job_typ AS OBJECT
(
    job_ID NUMBER,
    company_ID NUMBER,
    description NVARCHAR2 (1000),
    name NVARCHAR2 (200),
    application Application_tab,
    MAP MEMBER FUNCTION job_no
        RETURN NUMBER,
    MEMBER PROCEDURE no_of_applicants
);

CREATE TABLE Job_tab OF Job_typ
NESTED TABLE application
    STORE AS application_nt;
```

While trying to create all your types and keywords, I got the error:

```
[Error] PLS-00590 (10.1): PLS-00590: attempting to create a subtype UNDER a FINAL type
```

This is because Oracle doesn't allow creation of a subtype on a `FINAL` type. If you don't define any finalizing clause for the base type, the default is `FINAL`.

Read more on [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28371/adobjbas.htm#CIHFBHFC).

---

If you are coding for the real world (read industry), I'd advise against using nested tables as column types. You end up spending your entire life trying to nest and un-nest these. I'd suggest you normalize your schema as much as you can or need and leave nested tables for operations in PL/SQL code blocks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My design does extend beyond this and now I am trying to simplify it as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is completely correct and you just need to add
"**NOT FINAL**" end of
your script :

```
create or replace type user_typ as object(
user_id number(19,0),
username nvarchar2(40 char)
)
NOT FINAL;
```

Good luck